# How can I send multiple notification with "minishlink/web-push" pakckage?

Tags: laravel, push-notification, package

I am using ***"minishlink/web-push"*** package to send notification in my Laravel project.

```
Route::post("/admin/sendNotif/{sub}", function(PushSubscription $sub, Request $request){
    $webPush = new WebPush([
        "VAPID" => [
            "publicKey" => "BNbqX8M5NJJ...",
            "privateKey" => "i4I89hSrn-MGvp...",
            "subject" => "https://example.com"
            ]
        ]);
    $webPush->sendOneNotification(
        Subscription::create(json_decode($sub->data, true)),
        json_encode($request->input())
    );
    return redirect("/");
});
```

With this method, I can send only one notification:

```
    $webPush->sendOneNotification(
        Subscription::create(json_decode($sub->data, true)),
        json_encode($request->input())
    );
```

Is there a way I can send multiple notifications at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this readme for a better explanation of WebPush:

[web-push-php](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php)

### Code Snippet

```js
// send multiple notifications with payload
foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
    $webPush->queueNotification(
        $notification['subscription'],
        $notification['payload'] // optional (defaults null)
    );
}

/**
 * Check sent results
 * @var MessageSentReport $report
 */
foreach ($webPush->flush() as $report) {
    $endpoint = $report->getRequest()->getUri()->__toString();

    if ($report->isSuccess()) {
        echo "[v] Message sent successfully for subscription {$endpoint}.";
    } else {
        echo "[x] Message failed to sent for subscription {$endpoint}: {$report->getReason()}";
    }
}
```

### Explanation

- Loop through a notification array which contains the subscription object and the payload then queue the notification passing the two as arguments.
- Then flush the queue to send the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Because this package uses Google service, I doubt it can do this.  My suggestion is that you use ***Laravel echo*** : https://github.com/laravel/echo